# ic_drawer icon on actionbar

Tags: android, navigation

I am trying to get `ic_drawer` icon on actionbar. I think this is the way

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,  
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
            ) {};
```

I use it in an `AppCompatActivity` with a `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme. It returns a `null` value for `getActionBar()`. Even the `getSupportActionBar()` returns a `null` value. How do I do this?

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()` is what you want in an `AppCompatActivity`. Are you sure you're actually using that theme? Are you calling that method in the right place? Are you sure that it's `getSupportActionBar()` returning null that's the problem? What's your stack trace say?

Comment: got it after some searching. With AppCompatActivity I should have called `this.getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your theme in `res/values/styles.xml` do have actionBar. It must not inherit `NoActionBar` theme.